# SQL query for Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am working on a website (Joomla). I have used a component called "DJ classifieds" in which profiles can be registered. After registering the profile the user can click on a link to post the data. Drawback is that the user can post any number of times if he is registered once. I have made the user ID UNIQUE in DB to stop a user from posting his profile more than once. **But I want the admin's user ID to allow duplicates**. I have searched in google but unable to find the related answer. Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to create unique constraint where ID <> admin's user ID? And when  ID = admin's user ID then unique  constraint  wont work, right?

Comment: Yes MegaTron you're right

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL doesn't support such types of constraints.

You should use stored procudures for inserting data instead, so you can do some checking and validation.

Or you can to write a trigger to check for it.

Comment: I am unaware of it. Could you please explain me what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1138784 Yes, if you describe more details what do you do

Comment: I am building a website in which users register and post their data. Similar to job portals. A user registers, and after logging in he need to update his profile. To avoid multiple data on single registration, I made the user ID UNIQUE in phpmyadmin of that table. There are few users who asks admin to register their profiles on behalf of them. So the admin needs to post the data. But the user ID is unique which doesn't allow duplicates.
Let me know if you need any other details.